# Why is the form not shown on the website?

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms

I have a feedback form and it should be located on the main page along with other models. But alas, for some reason it refers to a non-existent template. And thus it is not shown on the site, although the model itself is present in the admin panel.

Please help me figure it out.
I was trying many ways to figure out it, but theres nothing

views.py

```
class MainDetail(CreateView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('success_page')
    form_class = ContactForm
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        search_query = request.GET.get('search', )
        model_2 = Jobs.objects.order_by()
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        portfolio = Portfolio.objects.prefetch_related('image')
        ctx = {
            'jobs':model_2,
            'portfolio': portfolio
        }
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return render(request, 'homepage.html', ctx)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Формируем сообщение для отправки
        data = form.data
        subject = f'Сообщение от {data["first_name"]} {data["last_name"]},Тема: ORDER {data["phone"]}'
        email(subject, data['message'])
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

model.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField ('Name', max_length=25)
    last_name = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=30)
    phone = models.EmailField ('Phone', max_length=15)
    message = models.TextField (max_length=400)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name= 'Feedback'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Feedsbacks'

    def __str__(self):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name= 'Feedback'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Feedsbacks'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

forms.py

```
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'message']
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput (
                attrs={'placeholder':'Name'}
            ),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'placeholder': 'Wash'}
            ),
            'phone': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={'placeholder': '+7 (123) 45-67-89'}
            ),
            'message': Textarea(
                attrs={
                    'placeholder': 'Message',
                    "rows":6,
                    "cols": 25
                }
            )
        }
```

html

```
<aside class="postcard">
     <form class="form" method="POST">
         <p>Order</p>
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{ form.as_p }}
         <div class="form-group">
             <input type="submit" value="Send">
         </div>
      </form>
</aside>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is your html file name?

Comment: homepage.html this my html

Comment: Can you rename the filename to `contact_form.html`?

Comment: Yes, but i prefer don't do it, I don't understand why it user contact_form.html like a  template

Comment: That's how `CreateView` construct the template name. See [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView.template_name_suffix) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but I tihink I understand what truble is. I think I have to use metod like get_context_data(self, **kwargs). But so far I don't understand how I can combine both forms and just models into one, huh. So I will try to do it

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the solution to all the troubles

```
class MainDetail(CreateView):
    model = Jobs
    model_2 = Portfolio
    model_3 = Contact
    template_name = 'homepage.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('success_page')
    form_class = ContactForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MainDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['first_form'] = ContactForm (self.request.POST)
        context['jobs'] = Jobs.objects.order_by()
        context['portfolio'] = Portfolio.objects.prefetch_related('image')
        return context
```